# How to test a Flutter model with a mocked viewmodel

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, provider

I'm trying to test a Flutter widget which users a viewmodel via Provider. Clicking the button should call a function on the viewmodel. I've mocked the viewmodel via Mocktail with a stubbed function when I then pass through a ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
 testWidgets('should call auth function when clicked', (tester) async {
      var mockUVM = MockUserViewModel();
      var mUM = UserModel();
      when(mockUVM.signIn).thenAnswer((_) => (Future(() => mUM)));

      await tester.pumpWidget(ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: mockUVM,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return const MaterialApp(home: ScreenLogin());
          }));

      await tester.tap(find.text('SIGN IN'));

      verify(mockUVM.signIn).called(greaterThan(0));
    });
```

The test fails as the mocked signIn method hasn't been called. Running it in debug shows runs the real method on the true usermodel.

Within ScreenLogin, the UserViewModel is passed via Provider to the button

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
        key: const Key('loginForm_raisedButton'),
        style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor:
                MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(theme.primaryColor)),
        label: const Text(
          'SIGN IN',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17),
        ),
        icon: const Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google, color: Colors.white),
        onPressed: () async => {
              Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false).signIn()
            });
  }
```

How can I test the button tap with a mocked viewmodel using Provider?

Comment: How is ScreenLogin implemented? Are you providing UserViewModel there?

Comment: The UserViewModel is passed by Provider within ScreenLogin to the button. I've added a code snippet in the main question